# Verb for answer before you

Tags: expressions, idioms

What is the expression for when somebody directs a question to you but somebody else answers before you?

Comment: To *preempt*, *to steal one's thunder*; synonyms available in any good thesaurus.

Comment: He *speaks in your name*, or he *cuts you off*. Read the entire comment of @DanBron to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[interject](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/interject?s=t)**

to interpose abruptly or sharply; interrupt with; throw in: *she interjected clever remarks*

Comment: This is the word I immediately thought of and then saw your answer. +1

Comment: Thank you, this one fits perfectly with the idea/example I was thinking.